# How to prevent overlay being poped by other code in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, overlay

I have some code like:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(spinnerOverlayThatPreventClick)
//some funcs
Navigator.of(context).pop() //pop the spinnerOverlay
```

But sometime by accident the overlay is wrongly pop-ed by other code (e.g. async push-pop of other dialog).

What is the correct way to do it? Is there some non-push/pop-based-way to show overlay?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html, for some working code ask google for `flutter overlay class`

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the overlay widget with a WillPopScope widget, then in the onWillPopScope propert method, return false.

this should prevent a pop() of that overlay widget

Comment: True... but would block the pop of other, still messup the stack....